# Is there a more rubylike way to do output_val = [ input_val, max ].min?

Tags: ruby, max, min

Occasionally I need to do something like this:

```
output_val = ( input_val < max ) ? input_val : max
```

and if I'm feeling stingy on space, I might opt for:

```
output_val = [ input_val, max ].min
```

Is there a third option that's concise without sacrificing expressiveness?

Comment: Unless you're trying to impress someone, the second snippet should be just fine.

Comment: @Asad, yes, but what if he's like most of us on SO??

Comment: @CarySwoveland Guilty as charged :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monkey patch! Doesn't get much more Rubylike than this.

```
class Numeric
  def unless_over(max)
    [self, max].min
  end
end
```

Example:

```ruby
133.unless_over(100) #=> 100
133.unless_over(150) #=> 133
```

Note: I wouldn't actually *do* this (I'd use your second example), but I'm guessing this is the spirit of the question.

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't do it either :)

Comment: It would be more general if it were defined on `Enumerable`. I actually have that in my library, and the method name is `at_most`.